# Are moderator flags private?

Tags: discussion, moderators, moderation

I recently used the "flag a moderator" function to raise a concern about another user's posts. I was quite surprised to see that flag [openly posted into a chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29671345#29671345), along with my username and a timestamp.

While I should stress that I couldn't personally give a damn if **all** of my flags were published, I was wondering what the *principle* was;

**Are moderators entitled to make flags public?**

Comment: Wait, that was a *flag*? I thought it was a comment O_o

Comment: @Ixrec - It was a [custom mod-flag](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uNUor.png).

Comment: I also thought it was a comment...

Comment: @AncientSwordRage - Nope

Comment: @Richard Out of curiosity, would you have minded had Thaddeus not included your name in the quote ?

Comment: @kallisar - Actually my initial concern was that Thaddeus mistakenly thought he was posting into the mod-chatroom and might say something inappropriate for general discourse.

Answer (score 19):

I am informed such a breach of protocol is non-standard. I apologize for any inconvenience or disturbance this may have caused. It will not happen again.

Comment: I remain undisturbed but the apology is appreciated.

Comment: Wait... has anyone published my flags?

Comment: @anaranjada - No, it looks like it was just that one flag from me. I think you'd already *commented* by that point (in the [chatroom you created](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39823/discussion-for-https-scifi-stackexchange-com-questions-128163-what-is-gained-by)) but no other flags of yours or mine (or anyone elses) seems to have been posted.

Comment: While I'm with Richard on the general idea (I wouldn't care if my flags were public, as they are always worded in a way that assumes they might be), I'm curious at your choice of terminology. Could you please clarify if this it **against the rules, or against standard protocol (which to my ESL ear implies that it's a typical custom, but not a rule)**.

Comment: I was informed this was considered something that was NOT done. Broadcasting of a flag to the general populace is NOT protocol in any fashion; it is considered something which should be apologized for. It was explained to me as being against the general rule set of the moderator's role on the site. Having been informed, I will endeavor to maintain the standard as instructed. Hope that helps.

Comment: If making a flag public is something that should be apologized for, why is there the option to do so in the first place?

Comment: @Thunderforge It'd be hard for SE to literally deprive us of the option of pressing Ctrl+C with the flag selected and then Ctrl+V in a public chatroom :-)