# Favorite Questions and answers from first and second quarter of 2020

Tags: discussion, blog

### Update

[Post is published.](https://thesffblog.com/2020/07/highlights-from-2020-1st-2nd-quarter/)

### Original

Apparently I forgot to do the first quarter favorites, I don't know if it was the pandemic or the earthquake, but something threw me off.

Please link to your favorite questions and answers which were either asked or answered from January 1st 2020 through June 30th 2020.

Your answers will be compiled into a blog post like previous [quarterly posts](https://thesffblog.com/category/qotw/).

I will be using DavRob60's queries for a baseline, but I really appreciate people voicing the ones they really enjoyed. Maybe you feel like you answered one really well, even if it didn't receive a lot of votes. Let me know about it.

- [Questions with most **Votes** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106579/questions-with-most-votes-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2020/01/01)
- [Questions with most **View** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106705/questions-with-most-view-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2020/01/01)
- [Questions with **best answer** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106709/questions-with-best-answer-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2020/01/01)

**I will also be linking all blog posts that happened within this half year. Also the [most controversial question](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/550327/most-controversial-posts-on-the-site-by-start-date) of the quarter. Also a sum of all the [bounties](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/618952/past-bounties-by-bounty-date) that were awarded.**

Also if there was a meta post you feel should be spotlighted those are also acceptable. Also! I really like the word also.

From a previous [blog post](https://thesffblog.com/2019/12/star-wars-episode-i-the-phantom-menace-1999-re-watch/):

> For my re-watch, I found Jar Jar to be significantly less annoying than I originally did

Comment: I see you're subliminally encouraging people to nominate questions about Jar Jar. Well played.

Answer (score 8):

### Breakout Questions

#### [Questions by particularly new/low rep users, with good answers](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/1247694/questions-with-best-answer-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2013%2F01%2F01&MinimumRep=500)

[Why did Lando give up his role as Administrator of Cloud City just to side with Leia, Chewie and the Rebellion?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/225925/why-did-lando-give-up-his-role-as-administrator-of-cloud-city-just-to-side-with)

[Can Harry Potter swim?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/227403/can-harry-potter-swim)

[In Star Trek, are food replicators also used by everyday people as a household item?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/225993/in-star-trek-are-food-replicators-also-used-by-everyday-people-as-a-household-i)

#### [Questions that standout on their own, by new/low rep askers](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/edit/1247697)

[Short story about distant-future researchers who rediscover the forgotten Earth shortly before it falls into the sun](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/226222/short-story-about-distant-future-researchers-who-rediscover-the-forgotten-earth)

[Sci-fi short story about extra sense that can be experienced by humans only once (probably from 1960's or 70's)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/229003/sci-fi-short-story-about-extra-sense-that-can-be-experienced-by-humans-only-once)

[Short story; scientists find mysterious alien man who refuses to talk to them](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/228356/short-story-scientists-find-mysterious-alien-man-who-refuses-to-talk-to-them)

[Why didn't the Federation try to replicate the experiment that sent them to another galaxy?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/227163/why-didnt-the-federation-try-to-replicate-the-experiment-that-sent-them-to-anot)

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to spotlight @Slytherincess' meta post; [Inactive Moderators (Again)](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12992/inactive-moderators-again)

I think it's fair to say that when someone as as widely respected as her raises this sort of concern, that it's something that many users are expressing in private.